# Google Docs inline pdf shows up as black and white

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am embedding pdfs(hosted at S3) in modals using the [google docs iframe](https://docs.google.com/viewer) in my rails app.  Here's the code:

```
$modalBody.append(
  "<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<%= @url %>&embedded=true' width='100%' height='800'></iframe>"
);
```

The issue is that sometimes(seemingly random) the pdfs show up in black and white even though the original upload was in color. The only hint I have is that the pdfs that render as black and white generally have very little color in them(like the one below). Any idea what's going on?

**AWS**

[AWS pdf link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/byrex/Appraisals/SK+18391.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAICY54SSXZZG5M7XA&Expires=1392232076&Signature=qZuJKSydVHTQgpIsMNqtnp9YCqU=&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEDQakALDssO4WczTB6jqbmbxgouaPHUX4CrlI0E6om36or647wJYkVJ1WTWiDDDb3xWQXb09KlJMrNDyGzcCxxCgp1HMngaXmf0%2bbEhOY4BK0rJYr9yL7Xs13IEbA6X672BfMmWz5cbJEiM3OY0EIm3Dh6%2b5WY43O2fOsMfeG2uBPifPOzjGsBGWRYBkOLa4C0pIXr7Hy3dQuNRDvbwzyqmcTLDgXhHrgZ8pegTLKhg/Eu88uesgIEvBLGU0Xl5OLni/jIPU76AahX3DTZ5PJvyKNjDXo/mLWUx8%2bAApldU2bchTOTbfEd06Oux8lNmTfIsqdT7pD0qX2aiWR8NGHezkuVHaSqm19UGuCgJenIXCjtUG8SCvie%2bXBQ==)

[image: screenshot of pdf]

**Google Docs**

[Google Docs link](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://s3.amazonaws.com/byrex/Appraisals/SK%2b18391.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAICY54SSXZZG5M7XA&Expires=1392232076&Signature=qZuJKSydVHTQgpIsMNqtnp9YCqU%253D&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEDQakALDssO4WczTB6jqbmbxgouaPHUX4CrlI0E6om36or647wJYkVJ1WTWiDDDb3xWQXb09KlJMrNDyGzcCxxCgp1HMngaXmf0%252BbEhOY4BK0rJYr9yL7Xs13IEbA6X672BfMmWz5cbJEiM3OY0EIm3Dh6%252B5WY43O2fOsMfeG2uBPifPOzjGsBGWRYBkOLa4C0pIXr7Hy3dQuNRDvbwzyqmcTLDgXhHrgZ8pegTLKhg/Eu88uesgIEvBLGU0Xl5OLni/jIPU76AahX3DTZ5PJvyKNjDXo/mLWUx8%252BAApldU2bchTOTbfEd06Oux8lNmTfIsqdT7pD0qX2aiWR8NGHezkuVHaSqm19UGuCgJenIXCjtUG8SCvie%252BXBQ%253D%253D) (You can get this by plugging the AWS link into [Google Docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer))

[image: google docs screenshot]

Comment: Is there any pattern to the pdfs that show up in black and white? Could be some sort of color space conversion issue.

Comment: The only pattern I can deduce is that the black and white issue seems to only occur when the amount of color in the original PDF is relatively low(such as the above screenshot).

Comment: We have a similar problem with our PDF, where the Google-Drive preview is of very low quality (only few different colors), while the downloaded version is fine

Comment: If you still need this answered, please update the document.  We definitely have been down this road, and can give an answer, but need to have a look at the document

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn I no longer have access to that bucket.  We ended up just moving away from the google doc viewer iframe.  However, I do think there is still value in an answer as it seems to be a fairly common problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the compression type of the RGB image in the PDF. I tried converting the RGB to CMYK which sort-of-works (I only have a really old utility for doing this). I also tried  editing the original to add another image: http://tonywilk.no-ip.org/testpdf/index.html the pdf file is at: http://tonywilk.no-ip.org/testpdf/test_out.pdf

This shows the colour for the added image with the original still monochrome - so Google viewer cannot handle the original's compression type.

Other than re-encoding the pdf's, I'm afraid it does not help you much - sorry !